# Solve $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi\over3} {{\sin^nx}\over \sin^nx+\cos^nx}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi\over3} {{\sin^nx}\over \sin^nx+\cos^nx}dx$$
I really don't know what to do. It was really simple if the upper limit was $\pi/2$, because I can change $x=\pi/2-t$, but in my case I have no idea.
Some help please?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using the complex exponential forms for sinx and cosx?

Comment: I just wanted that if available, please check the answer to confirm that the question is correct, because even http://www.integral-calculator.com/ didn't find any simplification for this definite integral.

Comment: The question is probably correct and the answer is probably $\tfrac{\pi}{3}-\tfrac{\pi}{4}=\tfrac{\pi}{12}$. Now all we need is an approach ;o).

Comment: @StackTD How did you get 'probable' answer?

Comment: If you can use the Dominated Convergence theorem, simply say that if $f_n(x)$ is your function, $f_n(x)\to 1$ if $\sin(x)>\cos(x)$, and $f_n(x)\to 0$ if $\cos(x)>\sin(x)$, and that $0\leq f_n(x)\leq g(x)=1$.

Comment: @JaideepKhare The convergence isn't uniform so you can't simply move the limit inside, but $f_n$ converges to a step-function which is 0 on $[0,\tfrac{\pi}{4}]$ and 1 on $[\tfrac{\pi}{4},\tfrac{\pi}{3}]$.

Comment: no time for a real answer, but in short:
Take $\cot(y)=x$ which means that the integral of interest reads

$$
-\int_{1/\sqrt{3}}^{\infty}dx\frac{1}{1+x^2}\frac{1}{1+x^n}=-\frac{\pi}{4}+\int_0^{1/\sqrt{3}}dx\frac{1}{1+x^2}\frac{1}{1+x^n}=\\-\frac{\pi}{4}+\int_0^{1/\sqrt{3}}dx\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\mathcal{O}(e^{-\log(3)n/2}/n)=\\ \frac{\pi}{12}+\mathcal{O}(e^{-\log(3)n/2}/n)
$$

Answer (score 9):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi\over3} {{\sin^nx}\over \sin^nx+\cos^nx}dx$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi\over3} \frac{1}{ \cot^n x+1} dx$$

We have that for $x \in (0,\frac{\pi}{4})$, that $1<\cot x$. Hence there $\frac{1}{ \cot^n x+1} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

We also have $0<\cot x<1$ for $x \in (\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{3})$. Hence there $\frac{1}{ \cot^n x+1} \to 1$.

So we have,

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} 1 dx$$

$$=\frac{\pi}{12}$$

Comment: I had the same idea (and result, see comment above); but is this allowed if $f_n \to f$ pointwise but not uniformly?

Comment: It's allowed by the dominated convergence theorem since $\frac1 {\cot^n(x)+1} \le 1$  on $(0, \pi/3)$.

Comment: good one...dct is by far the simplest approach here

Comment: the corrections to the above limit seem to be $ \sim Const \times 3^{-n/2}/n$ . Interesting...

Comment: $Const=\sqrt{3}/4$ if someone cares ;-)